# com.github.javaparser.JavaParser cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, javaparser

I wanna use javaparser with my plugin in eclipse. I can use/import all of JavaParser-Core classes except one. JavaParser class caused an error. 
How can i fix this?

Here is console output;

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.javaparser.JavaParser cannot be found by com.myplugin_1.0.0.qualifier
at     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:484)
at     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
at     org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

download this jar and add this to the classpath

http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/javaparser/javaparser-core/2.0.0/javaparser-core-2.0.0.jar

If your Java program is a simple class, add this jar file to the classpath using -cp  to the startup argument

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Eby

Comment: I thought the problem is in source code which i attached the jar. when i changed the source, nothing fixed.